# ASP.NET UpdatePanel library reference errors

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, dotnetnuke

I am having a problem with VS 2010 apparently losing it's ability to load an UpdatePanel in the middle of development and it is driving me crazy.  I am using VS2010 and building a user control with .NET 3.5, targeting DNN 5.x.

I have created a control to be used on a DNN website that utilizes an update panel.  When I develop the control by FTPing to the website and developing on it, everything works just fine.  I decided to move development to a local copy of DNN and create a web application project for the control.  Everything was working just fine at first.  After a few builds, I started to receive the following errors:

> The type or namespace name
>   'UpdateProgress' does not exist in the
>   namespace
>   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts'
>   (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)
>
> The type or namespace name
>   'UpdatePanel' does not exist in the
>   namespace
>   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts'
>   (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)

I figured I had messed something up along the way and screwed up a reference to the libraries, so I unloaded everything and reloaded the library references.  I continued to get the error and could not compile the control.  Finally, I decided to redo the entire project and import the code I had already written.  Everything was working just fine until a few builds later when the same error popped up.

I followed all of the same steps, unloading the references, reloading them, and finally deleting the project.  Each time I create a new project, and copy the exact same code into the .ascx files, they work just fine...for a few builds.  Last night, I compiled the library and tested the changes.  Everything was great so I closed the project and turned off the machine.  Turned it on this morning and received the build errors.  It is like I have a ticking timebomb in my computer that just shuts these things off.

Any ideas on what I am missing that might be causing this?  I don't know why a library would flicker on and off like this.  I have yet to run into this sort of a problem with any other project on my local machine and I really don't want to develop this through FTPing to the website, again.  Bleh!

Comment: After adding the references, try right-clicking the reference, select properties and set "Copy-local" to true.

Comment: @Tchami, just tried it (something I had not thought of yet) and am still getting the same errors.

Comment: Maybe adding the controls of System.Web.Extensions to web config might work. Check an asp.net 3.5 projects web.config

Comment: @reverseblade, I checked the web.config (for the DNN site) and even added the original web.config back to the control's project just to see if it would re-reference the library.

Comment: How are you adding the reference? And is ASP.NET Ajax installed on your machine?

Comment: @Tchami, I am creating a Web Application, to start, and it automatically references System.Web.Extensions (for .NET 3.5).  ASP.NET Ajax is installed (both for .NET 2.0 and 3.5).  I have tried to manually reference the DLL and just the namespace from Add Reference -> .NET -> System.Web.Extentions.  I can build the project just fine and test the update panels just fine.  It just sort of shuts off after a few builds.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My solution got into this weird state too.  It occurred after editing conflicts in the web-config after getting latest using AnkhSVN.
The error only showed in the page I had open in Visual Studio at the time.  It said it could no longer locate the UpdatePanel or UpdateProgress in System.Web.UI, which didn't make sense because I use these controls in my other pages.

**The Fix**:
Simply drag and drop an UpdatePanel from the toolbox onto the page throwing the error.  Clean and Rebuild and you're good to go.  All you have left to do is remove the UpdatePanel you just added.
I believe doing this re-wires things in the solution that I couldn't see.

Comment: I haven't run into this in a while (pretty much gave up on Web Forms in general) but if I run into it again I will be sure to try this out.  Thanks!

Comment: When I did this it changed from System.Web.UI.WebControls.UpdatePanel to System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel in the .designer.cs file (which fixed it). I think this had to do with editing the file on another machine. I'll have to look into it more later. Thanks!

Comment: I can't remember why I didn't mark this as the answer (I've done it plenty of times since then). I'm unmarking my answer and going to accept this one instead since it has actually worked for me in the past. (Sorry for witholding those points for so long!)  =)

Comment: This is only a temporary fix. Visual Studio is changing it back to *WebControls.* again and again... no matter how often I edit the designer file.

Comment: @lapsus -1, really?  The solution obviously works judging by the other upvotes. Maybe something is wrong or corrupted with your solution file or with getting-latest from your repository? My fix does not instruct you to edit the "designer file" (e.g. Somepage.aspx.design). It says to drag & drop controls from your control-toolbox onto the page itself where the markup is (e.g. Somepage.aspx), then Clean & Rebuild the entire Solution. Try closing all your open files (except for one asxp markup file) and do this. I hope it works. If it keeps happening, then I'd suggest creating a new solution.

Comment: As I said.. it does solve the problem - but only on a temporary basis. It does happen to many developers on different development machines here. The solutions were not migrated from 2.x to 4.x. These are shiny new SharePoint 2013 solutions. It's not clean & rebuild or repository related. If it only was that easy..

Comment: @xr280xr - did you ever get to the bottom of why that worked? Your suggestion just worked for me then and saved me a big headache so thanks very much, but I'm curious as to why one machine would reference UI.WebControls and another UI!

Answer (score 3):

If you will examine the new web.config file you will find the following (or something close) was added. I was able to add this compiler directive with no other changes and successfully compile.  ScriptManager is in the older version of the extensions .dll and needs to be bound.  It seems creating a new website will add the compiler directives but upgrading does not.

```
<!--/system.webServer  positional notes-->;

<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding appliesTo="v2.0.50727" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>

<!-- /configuration -->
```

Comment: thanks for your response!  I actually found that it was because I put my DNN controls directly in the DesktopModules folder (in separate projects from the rest of the installation) so I couldn't have the full web.config when I was testing the site.  I would rename it to web.config.old when testing.  As such, I would lose all references to assemblies when I started up the project again if I didn't rename it back before closing Visual Studio.  Thanks for your thoughts, though!

Comment: Your mention of the System.Web.Extensions library led me to add that reference to my project and it now recognizes System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel without having to go into the UI or changing the framework version.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in all my old Projects after updating to Framework 4.0.  I tried many times researching why this was happening and nothing I found would work.  My team spent over a year living with manually updating the `designer.vb` for UpdatePanel to have the right reference every time we changed the ASPX.

The issue happened to be in the project file's reference to AjaxControlToolkit.  The reference in the `.vbproj` file was version specific for 3.5.  So just updating the DLL didn't update the reference.  The solution was to remove the AjaxControlToolkit reference, save the project, and then add back the reference to `AjaxControlToolkit.dll`.

If you opened the project file in a text editor, you may have seen something like this:

```
<Reference Include="AjaxControlToolkit, Version=3.5.60623.0, Culture=neutral, 
    PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e, processorArchitecture=MSIL>
    <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
    <HintPath>bin\AjaxControlToolkit.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

If you did everything right it should look like this:

```
<Reference Include="AjaxControlToolkit">
    <HintPath>bin\AjaxControlToolkit.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```